# file.move and its invisible logical values

Tags: r

I used the function `file.move` to move written files from one folder within my directory to another subfolder.

Executing the function, the console prints red text depending on un/successful moved files **for each moved file** like this:

> 1 file moved. 0 failed.

Reading the documentation of the function within the `filesstrings` package, this is coming from "invisible" logical values depending on the success.

I now want to know how it is possible for me to get access to those value in a kind as that I can use them f.ex. as a counter (summation) of succeful/unsuccessful values printed, etc.?

Thanks for any help!

```
# Example code from "?file.move"
dir.create("dir")
files <- c("1litres_1.txt", "1litres_30.txt", "3litres_5.txt")
file.create(files)
file.move(files, "dir")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `?invisible`

> This function can be useful when it is desired to have functions return values that can be assigned, but which do not print when they are not assigned.

So you can directly do :

```
values <- filesstrings::file.move(files, "dir")
```

and the return logical values should be available in `values`.

Comment: I wanted to just add up those comments so that I can print them in one line and/or they don't show up in the console as the `file.move` command is used within a self-written function and now inbetween my `cat(<text>)` prints those texts appear. For data with more than 100 files there pop up exact the same amount of "1 files moved. [...]" lines which I don't like :)

Comment: @Capt.Krusty Do you want to use `suppressMessages` to avoid printing in the console? `If you do `sum(values)` you'll get how many files were successfully moved.

Comment: Looks like I was looking for `suppressMessages`! Thank you for your help!
PS: Tried to insert the values term and print out their sum, but this is equal to my counter so maybe this is something for another time when I set the showWarnings to TRUE and overwrite to FALSE ;D